# Adding a child div inside a video element, not showing

Tags: html, css

My goal is to have text over each video element (there are many of them). The video is showing, but the div inside it does not.

```
<video autoplay playsinline style="transform: rotate(0deg); width: 100%; height: 100%; position: relative">
  <div style="width: 100px; height: 30px; color: white; z-index: 1; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; background: green;">test</div>
</video>
```

In the element inspector, when I hover over the div, it does not show a box anywhere on the page. How to make it show up?

Comment: can you share jsfiddle or codepen something like that?

Comment: I'm almost certain you can't have divs inside `<video>`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video. If you want to have text over an element you're better off either wrapping the `<video>` with that `<div>` or placing the `<div>` outside `<video>`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Video elements cannot contain elements inside, unless the `video` tag is not supported. This is common practice to display an error message explaining the browser doesn't support `video`.

Place your `video` inside an element (like a `div`) and add that `div` next to it, as a sibling to the `video` element and not a child. Use `position` to place it inside:

```html
<div style="position: relative;">
  <video autoplay playsinline style="transform: rotate(0deg); width: 100%; height: 100%; position: relative"></video>
  <div style="width: 100px; height: 30px; color: white; z-index: 1; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; background: green;">test</div>
</div>
```

Make sure you post your full code to ensure we can help you properly.